# How to find timestamp of file on FTP server

Tags: ftp, python, timestamp

I need to find the latest created file in a FTP folder. However the FTP server is not returning full timestamps for files with the LIST command (missing the year):

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 owner    group               0 Nov  9 17:29 archive
drwxr-xr-x   2 owner    group               0 Nov  9 17:35 category
drwxr-xr-x   2 owner    group               0 Jan  9 07:21 images
```

And the MLSD command is not supported.

So currently I check the timestamp of each file with the MDTM command. Is there a more efficient way?

I am using the [ftplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html) wrapper.

Comment: It's far from obvious but your mention of `ftplib` and the inclusion of the `python` tag gives me he impression that you're looking for a programming solution. If so, this should have been asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I am after the FTP command to get the timestamps reliably and efficiently. Should that go on SO?

Answer (score 1):

man ftp says:

> ```
>  ls [remote-directory] [local-file]
>              Print a listing of the contents of a directory on the remote machine.
>              The listing includes any system-dependent information that the server
>              chooses to include; for example, most UNIX systems will produce output
>              from the command ‘ls -l’.  (See also nlist.)  If remote-directory is
>              left unspecified, the current working directory is used.  If interac‐
>              tive prompting is on, ftp will prompt the user to verify that the last
>              argument is indeed the target local file for receiving ls output.  If
>              no local file is specified, or if local-file is ‘-’, the output is
>              sent to the terminal.
> ```

So, *most UNIX systems will produce output from the command ‘ls -l’* and  such command either shows date or date and time, depending on the “age” of file:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group        4 ene 21 12:40 keepalive.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group   525292 oct  4  2013 Linux.svg
```

Taking into account you are *after the FTP command to get the timestamps reliably and efficiently*, I'm affraid your approach (MDTM command) is the only one not including programming stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try [ftputil](http://ftputil.sschwarzer.net). Although it is not a standard python module, not part of the batteries included, it has similar features as os.stat. That allows you to get detail file stats such as file creation date, size etc. It is a high-level interface to the ftplib.

You might also find this link useful -

http://mcdc.missouri.edu/libs/python/ftputil/ftputil.html

Comment: It says for 'lstat' function: Values for the time of the last modification may be rough, depending on the information from the server. For timestamps older than a year, this usually means that the precision of the modification timestamp value is not better than days. For newer files, the information may be accurate to a minute.